# Error with displaying/saving an NS advanced pdf/html template associated with a line that has no place in the code

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, netsuite, suitescript

When I finished writing the code to an NS advanced pdf template, I started to see an error that is not reflected in the code. Details about the error in 13 line: "Error on line 13, column 142 in template.
Detail...`<tr> kid is <p> not <td>: ignoring`.

I tried to remove the code from the given line in which it occurs, but it did not give any effect, even if there is a comment to the whole if or the line is shifted, the given error pops up.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
    <link name="NotoSans" type="font" subtype="truetype" src="${nsfont.NotoSans_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSans_Bold}" src-italic="${nsfont.NotoSans_Italic}" src-bolditalic="${nsfont.NotoSans_BoldItalic}" bytes="2" />
    <#if .locale == "zh_CN">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKsc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKsc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "zh_TW">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKtc" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKtc_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ja_JP">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKjp" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKjp_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "ko_KR">
        <link name="NotoSansCJKkr" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansCJKkr_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    <#elseif .locale == "th_TH"> <!-- in this line error appears -->
        <link name="NotoSansThai" type="font" subtype="opentype" src="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Regular}" src-bold="${nsfont.NotoSansThai_Bold}" bytes="2" />
    </#if>
    <style type="text/css">table { font-size: 9pt; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
th { font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px 6px 3px; background-color: #e3e3e3; color: #333333; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px; }
td { padding: 4px 6px; }
b { font-weight: bold; color: #333333; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</pdf>
```

How can I remove this error, or what could i do to solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your error message does not match up with an actual line in your template is due to how NetSuite processes Advanced PDF/HTML templates. There are two libraries at play. Firstly, your template is processed by [Freemarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/) to merge in the fields from the record and produce an XML document, which is then passed to the [BFO](https://bfo.com/products/report/) engine which renders the PDF. If there is an error in the BFO stage, the line number displayed will refer to a line in the generated Freemarker output, not in your original template.

In terms of the actual error you are experiencing, it sounds like your template has a `<p>` tag as a direct child of a `<tr>`.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <p>Problematic p tag (direct child of table row element)</p>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You need to add a `<td>` tag

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
       <p>Paragraph is now correctly in a table cell (td)</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now i understand whats about this lines, but the problem was easier than i though. I put `float: left;`; in styles and everything broke down. This error was hard to find with no info about that.

Answer (score 0):

Use relational child tag, I got issue:
" kid  not  or : ignoring"
Cant use the table after the pdf tag, We should use the head tag first.

Comment: You could have added some debugging details.